# How to store performance records in order to do a time scaled report

Tags: c#, database, database-design, graph

I am busy writing a program for our company to monitor the performance of some systems of ours.

So basically every minute I will receive values with its current state. I will be storing them in a database. Thats all go and fine.

But now I need to be able to generate a report (well graph) of its performance over a time scale. That being hour, day, week, month year.

Now thats all well i can jsut query it with the time stamp. but when generating a year report I really donot need the accuracy to one minute and then I need to store 60*24*568 records per machine per year.

I want to some how store all the values for and then summarise them to reduce the amount of data needed to be stored.  so when I generate a yearly report it will look at say every 2 days. rather than every minute and same for a month it can look at everyday or every half hour.

Now my question is actually. How do I store this in the database?

Should I make tables for each summarized version  so minute => hour => day => week etc.

Or do i keep one big table with all the entries and just use sql to sumarise it etc.

I have never had to do anything like this before and I dont really know where to even start thinking. It sounds abit like data warehousing, but please note this is not oh a huge scale. It will be monitoring 5 -10 services with a web interface. The Idea I have in mind I actually got from Mikrotik Rotuers. I doubt many of oyu would have worked with them. But they have a great resource graphing system in there that is simple but displays what it need.

like this:
[image: Picture of graphs]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep the original table in the grain of minutes. Because in future your needs may change. Like 2 days to 1 day or even 6 hours once. To efficiently manage this table consider partitioning the table. Create a another table which has a summarized data. Write a sql to insert the aggregation table from the original table. So basically you are doing extract, transform and load (ETL) here. Hope it helps.